# Remove meta from user

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have added ACF Post Object field to a user(field key is `field_5beda4b10dc7d`). I am trying to remove this field value from a user based on the user ID, ACF Key, and post id. Am I missing something?

```
 delete_user_meta(1, 'field_5beda4b10dc7d', 128);
```

Comment: What is your question? Tell us as an [edit], in the question, what you want to do, show what you have tried including a [mcve] and tell us what results you got, including errors or messages. You may get better results over on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

You are using `delete_user_meta()` wrong. Look at the documentation:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/delete_user_meta

The third parameter does the following:

> **$meta_value** (string) (optional) Optional. Metadata value. Must be serializable if non-scalar. If specified, only delete metadata entries
>   with this value. Otherwise, delete all entries with the specified
>   meta_key. Pass `null`, `false`, or an empty string to skip this check.
>   (For backward compatibility, it is not possible to pass an empty
>   string to delete those entries with an empty string for a value.

What you currently say is: Delete user meta where

```
user_id = 1
meta_key = field_5beda4b10dc7d
meta_value = 128
```

This is probably not true in most cases. Probably you just have to *ommit the third parameter* in order to achieve your goal.